# How to fire Click-Event in Templated-Button

Tags: c#, wpf, command, custom-controls

I have searched for this issue but didn't found any Solutions.

I have a Templated-Button with an Image in Button.Template. This Button is Part of a CustomControl.

```html
<Button x:Name="PART_DELETESEARCHBUTTON"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomDeleteButtonStyle}"
        Command="{x:Static local:CustomSearchControl.DeleteCommand}"
        Width="20" Height="20"
        Margin="0,0,5,0">
  <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
          <Image x:Name="PART_IMGDELETE" 
                 Source="{DynamicResource _Av_PinClose_Dark}"
                 Cursor="Hand"
                 Margin="2"/>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
              </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
```

In Class of the CustomControl the Command for the Button is implemented:

```css
static CustomSearchControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomSearchControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomSearchControl)));

    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(CustomSearchControl),
                new CommandBinding(CustomSearchControl.DeleteCommand, C_DeleteCommand));
}

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
}

static void C_DeleteCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomSearchControl mycontrol = sender as CustomSearchControl;
    mycontrol.SearchText = "";
}
public static readonly ICommand DeleteCommand = new RoutedUICommand("DeleteCommand", "DeleteCommand",
                                    typeof(CustomSearchControl),
                                            new InputGestureCollection(new InputGesture[] { new KeyGesture(Key.Enter), new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick) }));
```

Now, if MouseClick on Button (Image) the Command isn't fired. When removing Button.Template with Image, all works fine.

How can the MouseClick on the Templated.ButtonImage binded to the Command?

Or is there annother way to solve this?

And secondly: The DeleteCommand clears a TextBox in this CustomControl. That works, but after Clearing, the TextBox lost the Focus. What is to do that the TextBox gets the Focus again after Click on Button??? Trigger or so???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't recreate the problem with the command not executing. It's working fine for me.

For the focus issue, the button gets focus when it's clicked. You'll have to explicitly set focus back to the textbox. That's easy. If it doesn't have a name in the template, give it one; I called mine "PART_SearchTextBox" but you can substitute your own name.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _PART_SearchTextBox = (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("PART_SearchTextBox");
}

public void ClearSearchText()
{
    SearchText = "";
    _PART_SearchTextBox.Focus();
}

private TextBox _PART_SearchTextBox;

static void C_DeleteCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomSearchControl mycontrol = sender as CustomSearchControl;
    mycontrol.ClearSearchText();
}
```

And in the CustomSearchControl template, name the textbox `PART_SearchTextBox`:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="PART_SearchTextBox"
    Text="{Binding SearchText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    ...etc...
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, in a little ExampleProject the command is working for me and with your tips focus is working fine.

Comment: I had used my CustomControl in a big App and there the command isn't fired. Obviosly there are other trouble with other Controls in the big App. So now I have to search for the other issue, perhaps some other Control or behavior overwrites something in my SearchCustomControl.

Comment: @Jürgen You put a breakpoint in `C_DeleteCommand()` and it's definitely not getting called?

Comment: I 've tried with breakpoint in C_DeleteCommand() but definitely not called :-( 
I think in my big App there are some other MouseBehaviors that eats the MouseDown. That will be a great search :-( for me

Comment: in my big App i have the same issue with my SearchTextProperty in CustomControl. The Property gets only the starting value:
<local:CustomSearchControl SearchText="Test"...
Do you have any tip, where I can search for???

Comment: You'll have to describe the behavior in more detail, and you'll have to give me a more complete code sample.

Comment: Sorry for this late post. I wrote an answer with code of Sample Project that shows the issues, but my answer had been deleted from Bhargav Rao. I don't know why??? He didn't explain why.

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was a MultiBinding-Converter, who manage Visibility of DeleteButton. Now I use ControlTemplate.MultiTrigger for Visibility and it works.

Comment: What do you mean about the answer? Who is Bhargav Rao? If you posted part of your question as an answer, that should be deleted. Anyway, I'm glad you resolved the issue.

Comment: @Jürgen One thing I noticed in your code was that `CustomSearchTestControl` halfway pretends to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but of course it doesn't, so nobody will ever be subscribes to the notification when `SuchText` changes. But don't do that anyway. **Do not** use such properties on a control. Do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a control. Make `SuchText` a dependency property. Any property on a control should be a dependency property, because only a dependency property can be the target of a binding.

Comment: @Jürgen I suspect that may be your problem.

Comment: @Jürgen Another point: `Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on `IsEnabled`. Those properties mean absolutely nothing in that context. Don't use them again until you look them up and understand what they do. Don't add random stuff to your code. That's not a good way to do programming.

Comment: @Jürgen I've solved all the problems in your code. The definition of `SuchText` was a problem but I found more problems and got it working now. You should post a new question, I'll answer it. I want my 25 more points! @ me as soon as you've got it posted.